# Changing localization on-the-fly

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm developing a multilingual app for WP8.

I've read [this blog entry](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/02/01/tips-for-localizing-windows-phone-8-xaml-apps-part1.aspx), but I find the "Enabling the user to change the language on the fly" step too cumbersome.

Is it possible to somehow refresh the Language and Text attributes of UI elements for the whole app, or at least page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with the method in the article is that the elements of the current page are not automatically updated because they are already rendered, and you need to update the strings in code.

A possible solution is to reload the page when changing the language. The `SetUILanguage` method would look like:

```
private void SetUILanguage(string locale)
{
    // Set this thread's current culture to the culture associated with the selected locale.
    CultureInfo newCulture = new CultureInfo(locale);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = newCulture;

    // Set the FlowDirection of the RootFrame to match the new culture.
    FlowDirection flow = (FlowDirection)Enum.Parse(typeof(FlowDirection),
        AppResources.ResourceFlowDirection);
    App.RootFrame.FlowDirection = flow;

    // Set the Language of the RootFrame to match the new culture.
    App.RootFrame.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(AppResources.ResourceLanguage);

    // Refresh the page in order to localize already rendered elements
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(NavigationService.Source + "?Refresh=true", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

That way the elements will be re-rendered, and will show the localized strings, without the need of changing them one by one.

Comment: That seems to bork the phone's Back button functionality. Is there a way to do a `Navigate` which won't be navigatable back?

Comment: Just call NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry() to remove the last page in the BackStack.

Comment: Hi, this helped me, and works fine. But already loaded pages(before the culture change) are not updating the change. Can u please tell me , how to reload the previously rendered pages, so that language change will be affect. Thank you in advance.